# Pulling rows with SQL MAXDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to run a query from a HR table. I'm bringing in all employees and their dependents who share the same 'Primary_Key_Value'. My statement works but I'm getting duplicates because some dependents have multiple MED_COV_EFFECTIVE_DATEs. I need to bring in only the lastest or MAX date. When I try to use the MAX(MED_COV_EFFECTIVE_DATE) function, I'm getting errors. Can someone please help me?

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, RECORD_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, HIRE_DATE,
                RELATIONSHIP_CODE, MED_COV_EFFECTIVE_DATE, SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER

FROM COVERAGE_TABLE T1
WHERE T1.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE IN
(
  SELECT T2.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE
  FROM COVERAGE_TABLE T2
   WHERE T2.HIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL 

)

ORDER BY PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, RECORD_ID
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is "group by". Happy reasearch.

Comment: I'm using SQL server

Comment: You should provide schema information and sample data. It seems your `PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE` is ***not*** a primary key if you're getting duplicates.

Comment: Try it with "Max" and "Group by" and let us know if you are struck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dang, wasn't thinking about inner select can only return 1 column earlier.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT T2.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, MAX(T2.Med_Cov_Effective_Date)
INTO #MostRecentCoveredKeys
FROM COVERAGE_TABLE T2
WHERE T2.HIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY T2.Primary_Key_Value
```

This should give you a unique set of Primary_Key_Values.

Or CTE Version:

```
; WITH MostRecentCoveredKeys
AS
SELECT T2.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, MAX(T2.Med_Cov_Effective_Date)
FROM COVERAGE_TABLE T2
WHERE T2.HIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY T2.Primary_Key_Value
```

Then JOIN the original table and cte (or temp table) like so:

```
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, RECORD_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, 
       HIRE_DATE, RELATIONSHIP_CODE, MED_COV_EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
       SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER
FROM COVERAGE_TABLE T1
INNER JOIN MostRecentCoveredKeys mrck
  ON mrck.Primary_Key_Value = T1.Primary_Key_Value
ORDER BY T1.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, T1.RECORD_ID

--you need to include the '#' in front of table name 
--on join if using the temp table version
--DROP TABLE #MostRecentCoveredKeys
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this. 'Subselect has too many fields'

Comment: I don't have 'create' permissions. So this isn't working for me. Can you show me how you would do this in a CTE? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This query will fetch the latest data:

```
SELECT B.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, B.RECORD_ID, B.LAST_NAME, B.FIRST_NAME,   
  B.DATE_OF_BIRTH, B.HIRE_DATE, B.RELATIONSHIP_CODE, 
  B.MED_COV_EFFECTIVE_DATE, B.SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER
FROM
(SELECT PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, MAX(MED_COV_EFFECTIVE_DATE) MAX_DATE
 FROM COVERAGE_TABLE
 WHERE HIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP BY PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE) A INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM COVERAGE_TABLE 
 WHERE HIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL) B
ON A.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE=B.PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE AND A.MAX_DATE=B.MED_COV_EFFECTIVE_DATE;
```

Comment: My query was bringing back over 200,000 rows, This query is bring back over a million. I'm looking now at the data to see if I can see what's duplicating...

Comment: If that's the case it means there are data that are inputted on the same day for a primary_key_value.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with a as
(
  select 
    *
    ,row_number() over(partition by PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, order by Med_Cov_Effective_Date desc) rn
  FROM COVERAGE_TABLE T1
  WHERE HIRE_DATE IS NOT NULL 
)
select *
from a
where rn=1
ORDER BY PRIMARY_KEY_VALUE, RECORD_ID
```

Comment: While running this code, I'm only returning one row.